# How to sort ListView.builder in decreasing order?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I want to make a list View .builder in decreasing sort can you help me?

```
List View .builder(
item Count: ..,
item Builder: (Build Context context , int i){..}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**.sort Method**

*referring to [Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html)*

**example 1**

```
var numbers = ['two', 'three', 'four'];
// Sort from shortest to longest.
numbers.sort((a, b) => 
a.length.compareTo(b.length));
print(numbers);  // [two, four, three]
```

**example 2**

```
List<int> nums = [13, 2, -11];
nums.sort();
print(nums);  // [-11, 2, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here **entries** is my list name as

```
final List<String> entries = <String>['A','B','C'];
```

```
    int length = entries.length;
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: entries.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            height: 50,
            child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${entries[length - 1 - index]}')),
          );
        });
```

[image: Output is as shown in image below]